# Play AAC encoded Webstream in NEW media3.exoPlayer

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, exoplayer2.x, android-media3

I'm trying to create a simple Jetpack Compose, Kotlin app that plays [this RAW aac encoded webstream](https://archives.kdvs.org/stream). Found out that the basic mediaPlayer doesn't support AAC encoded files, so after some digging I found that media3's exoPlayer is probably the most up-to-date way to play this webstream. However I know that exoPlayer2 is depreciated and haven't found much documentation on using media3's exoPlayer to play a webstream in the first place. I was wondering if anyone knows how to do this or would be able to point me in the direction of some resources.

Thank you!!